# How do I fit confidence bands to a custom function in R?

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I'm just beginning in R and am struggling to add confidence intervals to a function that I defined. I have seen plenty of examples for linear models and I know that ggplot2 can do this for some functions. However, fitting the bands to my custom function is proving tricky. Below I have the data and my function:

```
data<-matrix(c(0.08, 0.1, 0.12, 0.13, 0.49, 0.11, 0.12, 0.15, 0.22, 0.47, 7, 8 , 9, 21, 30, 3, 8, 13, 15, 17),ncol=2)
mycurve<-function(x){a+(b*log(x))}
plot(data)
curve(mycurve,add=T)
```

This is one example, but I have a few more datasets and custom curve functions that I need to do this to in addition to this one.
I would appreciate it if someone could suggest a way of doing this using either `plot` or `ggplot` (e.g. maybe using `geom_ribbon`?). I have spent quite a while searching stackoverflow, but haven't yet found a solution. If there is one, perhaps you could point me to it...

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Sorry, I forgot to add the parameters for `a` and `b`. They are:

```
a<-31
b<-9
```

Edit 2: I have tried the suggestions by @Ben Bolker and @Marcin Kosinski to use geom_smooth and plotted that along with my custom curve:

`data<-as.data.frame(data) #So that ggplot can use it`
`ggplot(data,aes(V1,V2))+geom_smooth(method="lm",formula=y~1+log(x))+
geom_point()+stat_function(fun=mycurve,color="red")`

The result is:
[image]

The red curve is my custom function that I need to use. So my problem is that I need `geom_smooth` to be using that function (or an alternative approach that will yield the same results).

Thanks for the help so far!

Edit3: Covariance matrix is:

`29.3897       14.5805

14.5805       8.01302`

Comment: This seems like more of a statistics question: "How do I define confidence intervals for my custom function?" If you *have* confidence bands, `geom_ribbon` is indeed a great way to go, but it seems your problem is in what the confidence bands should be.

Comment: In this particular case, I would just fit a linear model `lm(y ~ log(x))` and then simulate based on the model fit, `arm::sim` makes this nice and easy.

Comment: @Gregor, totally agree with your first comment.  As far as your second goes, `geom_smooth(method="lm",formula=y~1+log(x))` should work fine.

Comment: @Gregor: I will follow your advice on the first point and try to solve this from the statistical perspective. Appreciate the comments.

Comment: @DirkSnyman Confidence intervals result from the fitting procedure (you get standard errors around your coefficients estimates and correlations between them and based on that can generate confidence bands). Since you seem to have coefficient estimates already, generating a confidence interval (by any method I can think of) will **require** an estimate of the uncertainty in your parameters.

Comment: @Gregor I do have uncertainty of the parameters. The error for `a` is 5 and for `b` it is 2. The curve was fitted in TableCurve.

Comment: are those standard errors?  What is the correlation/covariance between the parameter estimates?

Comment: can you show us the results from http://www.systat.co.kr/products/TableCurve2D/help/1099.html ?

Comment: @BenBolker I've added it to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not said anything about where a and b come from.  It is not clear that you are doing any statistics for which confidence bands make sense.  If a and b are fixed/known constants then there is no need for confidence bands, or the confidence bands have 0 width and are the same as the prediction line.

If a and b are estimates of some parameter then there is the possibility of confidence bands, but the correct values depend on how a and b were calculated.

Comment: I fitted the original curve in TableCurve software. So `a` and `b` are the estimated parameters from that process. I have error estimates for both of these. For `a` it is 5 and for `b` it is 2.

Comment: @DirkSnyman, what method did TableCurve use to find a and b?  if it had been ordinary least squares then the curve would  have matched the geom_smooth results, so there must be something more going on.

Comment: it was indeed least squares. TableCurve gave the equation as y=a+blnx with a=31.02 (s.e.= 5.4) and b=9.9 (s.e.=2.8). So I used the equation and parameter values for drawing my graphs in R as posted above.

Comment: @DirkSnyman, Then either TableCurve is doing something wrong, ggplot is doing something wrong, or there is still something differnt (maybe TableCurve fit a non-linear least squares model).  Actually what I think is happening is that you are rounding too much.  I fit the model in R and the coefficients round to your values, but if I run your code at the top setting a and b to the computed values (no rounding) then the red and blue lines are essentially the same so you can use the `geom_smooth` approach.

Comment: you're right. It was a rounding problem. I managed to get the graphs working for `y=a+b*ln(x)` and for `y=a+be^-x`. However, when I get to other functions e.g. `y=a+b*ln(x)/x` then I can't seem to get it right. And I have no idea what to do with `y=a*sin(2*pi*x/c+b)` or `y=a*exp((x-b+c-c*d*exp((x-c*ln(d)-b)/c))/(cd))`. Thanks for your excellent help so far!

Answer (score 0):

Have you maybe seen geom_smooth?

```
data<-matrix(c(0.08, 0.1, 0.12, 0.13, 0.49, 0.11, 0.12, 0.15, 0.22, 0.47, 7, 8 , 9, 21, 30, 3, 8, 13, 15, 17),ncol=2)
library(ggplot2)
qplot(data[,1], data[,2])+geom_smooth()
```

Comment: Yes, but geom_smooth uses standard functions (lm, glm, gam, loess, rlm). If you run my code, you'll see what the shape of the curve must look like. If there is a way to use my own function with it, I haven't figured that out yet and would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Go and check @Ben Bolker comment about grom_smooth on your question